# Angular 2 variable in template is undefined

Tags: angular, href

I am declaring a variable in my component.

E.g.

```
let link = 'https://google.com'
```

But if I use it in my template, it is not there

E.g

```
{{ link }} -> has no output
href="#{{link}}" -> resolved into href="#"
[attr.href]="link" -> resolves into nothing
[attr.href]="link+'#'" -> resolves into href="undefined/#"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
let link = 'https://google.com'
```

to

```
link:string = 'https://google.com';
```

This code

```
let link = 'https://google.com'
```

is a statement and can only be used within the constructor or a method or function, but not at a class' top-level where only declarations are allowed.

Comment: This throws some errors in the console:
'unused label' & 'cannot find name "string"'
My IDE declares 'link' as: TS7028: Unused Label
and 'string' as: TS2304: Cannot find name 'string'

Comment: Please post more code. We have no way of knowing where in your application the code in your question is used.

Comment: Okay I made a mistake here. I declared it in the constructor. I moved it now out of it, so it works now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

should be

```
link = 'https://google.com'
```

instedad of `let`

let is used only for block scope, for using that variable in the template you have to declare that variable,

> PS: use `let` only to use wihtin the method/function

for more info on  `let`  see here

- https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/let.html